# Fabric unable to add new organization

Tags: google-fabric

I want to use the same app for different environments and I found this in the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html),

> Apps with Multiple Environments
>
> Let’s say you have an app called MyAwesomeApp and you want to keep the
>   bundle id the same, even though you have a staging, dev and prod
>   version of your app.
>
> The easiest thing to do is create a separate organization for each
>   version, onboard each version of MyAwesomeApp to the corresponding org
>   (just make sure you grab the new API key for each org) and you’re all
>   set. Why do it this way?
>
> Keeps your crashes separated by org
>   Add different team members to each org to control who has access to prod vs staging, etc.

I am trying to add a new organization in Fabric but when I do so it never gets added. No errors or warnings but it never shows up. Tried refreshing, logging in/out, different browser etc.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug with Fabric on Mozilla Firefox, Mac OS. I tried with Safari it worked.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Glad you're all set using Safari. I'll do more testing on Firefox to try and reproduce.

Comment: works on Chrome as well.
@MikeBonnell the error still exists on Firefox

Comment: Thanks, I'd recommend using Safari or Chrome to add new organizations.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I think you guys should fix this issue.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, this bug still exists and is a serious issue for Firefox users. I really hope that it's not part of Google's strategy to not support competing browsers in this way.

Comment: I'm no longer working on the product, so I don't know the current status. Since Fabric is being retired March 31, 2020, my best guess is that the bug will not be fixed in Fabric. If you hit a similar issue in Firebase, then I'd recommend filing a bug here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs/.